# Errors when using align block

Tags: equations, align

Whilst working on [a chemistry report](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1C6tehfhzO1q9ksvcAVnPykLYLf7-gU3C) I wanted to align some calculations so I made the following:

```
\begin{align}
$\text{Concentratie \ce{H2C2O4}: }&  6,5094 \frac{g}{L} $\\
$\text{Aantal gram \ce{H2C2O4}: }&  25 \cdot 10^{-3} * 6,5094 = 0,162735 \text{ gram } \ce{H2C2O4}$\\
$\text{Aantal mol \ce{H2C2O4}: }&  \frac{0,162735}{2\cdot 1,008 + 2 \cdot 12,01 + 4 \cdot 16} = \frac{0,162735}{90,036} = 0,0018 \text{ mol }$\\
\end{align}
```

Now the problem is that I am getting a lot of errors on the `\end{align}` line:

[image]

PS. Some of the text might not make sense since as it is in Dutch.

Comment: `align` enters math mode so remove all the `$`

Comment: also, you shouldn't have `\\ ` on the last line of an `align` block.  it only leaves extra space (usually unwanted) after the block.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest you also load `siunitx` and use this code:

```
\usepackage{siunitx}
\sisetup{output-decimal-marker = {,}}

\begin{document}
 ..................
 \begin{alignat}{2}
  & \text{Concentratie \ce{H2C2O4}: }&\quad & \SI[per-mode=fraction]{6,5094}{\g\per\L} \\
 & \text{Aantal gram \ce{H2C2O4}: }& & \num{25 e-3} * \num{6,5094} = \SI{0,162735}{\gram}~ \ce{H2C2O4} \\
 & \text{Aantal mol \ce{H2C2O4}: }& & \frac{\num{0,162735}}{2\cdot \num{1,008} + 2\cdot 12{,}01 + 4 \cdot 16} = \frac{\num{0,162735}}{90{,}036} =\SI{ 0,0018}{\mol}
\end{alignat}
.............
\end{document}
```

[image]

*Edit:*

For non-indenting equations, you can play with the `flalign` environment, or nest the above solution in a `fleqn`  environment (defined in `nccmath`, a very useful complement to `amsmath`):

```
\begin{flalign}
  & \text{Concentratie \ce{H2C2O4}: }&\quad & \SI[per-mode=fraction]{6,5094}{\g\per\L} &\qquad \\
 & \text{Aantal gram \ce{H2C2O4}: }& & \num{25 e-3} * \num{6,5094} = \SI{0,162735}{\gram}~ \ce{H2C2O4} \\
 & \text{Aantal mol \ce{H2C2O4}: }& & \frac{\num{0,162735}}{2 · \num{1,008} + 2 · 12{,}01 + 4 · 16} = \frac{\num{0,162735}}{90{,}036} =\SI{ 0,0018}{\mol}
\end{flalign}
\bigskip
\begin{fleqn} %requires nccmath
    \begin{alignat}{2}
  & \text{Concentratie \ce{H2C2O4}: }&\quad & \SI[per-mode=fraction]{6,5094}{\g\per\L} \\
 & \text{Aantal gram \ce{H2C2O4}: }& & \num{25 e-3} * \num{6,5094} = \SI{0,162735}{\gram}~ \ce{H2C2O4} \\
 & \text{Aantal mol \ce{H2C2O4}: }& & \frac{\num{0,162735}}{2 · \num{1,008} + 2 · 12{,}01 + 4 · 16} = \frac{\num{0,162735}}{90{,}036} =\SI{ 0,0018}{\mol}
\end{alignat}
\end{flalign}
```

[image]

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer. I just have one more question. If i do it like this the equations indent. Can i remove that indent. I tried removing the leading '&' but that doesn't look like it works.

Comment: @Naugrim00: I've added two variants of what you  want.